# Regular expression - excluding a character

Tags: ruby, regex

Here is an example:

> s="abcd+subtext@example.com"
>
> s.match(/+[^@]*/)
>
> Result => "+subtext"

The thing is, i do not want to include "+" in there. I want the result to be "subtext", without the +

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use parentheses in the regular expression to create a match group:

```
s="abcd+subtext@example.com"
s =~ /\+([^@]*)/ && $1
=> "subtext"
```

Comment: Another syntax for this is `s[/\+([^@]*)/, 1]`.

Comment: @mckeed, I didn't know that.  Very nice!

Comment: thanks folks! are these only for ruby? Also, what does the && stands for?

Comment: @ming yeow, every regular expression engine I've ever used has match groups.  && is a short-curcuit logical and.  In this context, it means "only evaluate $1 if s matches the regular expression, otherwise return nil.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a positive lookbehind assertion, which I believe is written like this:

```
s.match(/(?<=\+)[^@]*/)
```

*EDIT*: So I just noticed this is a Ruby question, and I don't know if this feature is in Ruby (I'm not a Ruby programmer myself). If it is, you can use it; if not... I'll delete this.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\+([^@]+)
```

I like to use [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) for playing around with regular expressions. Makes debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ruby very well, but if you add capturing around the portion you want it should work. ie: `\+([^@]*)`

You can test these with Rubular. This specific match is here: http://www.rubular.com/r/pqFza9jlmX